# Xunit console runner hangs while using reportportal option

Tags: xunit, xulrunner, reportportal

Command :

xunit.console path\test.dll -reportportal -html test.html

xunit console runner hangs after executing the last testmethods.

Answer (score -1):

Please get the latest release. That should fix the problem.

https://github.com/reportportal/agent-net-xunit/releases/tag/1.0.1